# Java, AutoCloseable: Должен ли ресурс освобождать родительский ресурс?

Tags: java

Сразу приведу свой пример. У меня имеется пул соединений с базой данных от библиотеки hikaricp:

```
HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(...);      
// работа с dataSource
dataSource.close();
```

В данном случае `dataSource` - это ресурс, который надо освобождать с помощью метода `close`.

Но мне не нравится стандартный `jdbc` и я сделал обертку для него:

```
HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(...);
JDBCWrapper jdbcWrapper = new JDBCWrapper(dataSource);
// работа с wrapper
wrapper.close();
dataSource.close();
```

Класс `JDBCWrapper` это обертка для работы с `jdbc`. Но внутри себя она создает собственные ресурсы, например, пул потоков для асинхронных запросов, по этому эта оберка тоже является ресурсом и имеет метод `close` для их освобождения.

Вопрос: должна ли обертка `JDBCWrapper` при вызове ее метода `close` так же освобождать `dataSource`?

С одной стороны `dataSource` находится внутри обертки `JDBCWrapper` и тоже должен освободиться, а с другой стороны этот ресурс с точки зрения обертки был получен "извне", откуда обертке знать, возможно, этот ресурс еще кому-то нужен там извне.

Если что, я не ищу инструмент для работы с базой данных, я хочу разобрать именно этот пример.

Comment: Система простая всё что вы не создавали сами, не уничтожаете. Открыли соединение - закройте. Получили - верните

Comment: если задокументировать поведение (декларировать, что `JDBCWrapper` становится владельцем `dataSource`) - то не просто можно, а нужно закрывать внутри wrapper-а. Пример с потоками: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44676137/4908529

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Все хорошо, что хорошо кончается (Уильям Шекспир)

Система как я уже упомянул, такая

Если вы создаёте объект, то позаботесь о его успешной утилизации (убрать ненужные ссылки, для упешной работы GC). Если же объект получает через Dependancy Injection то будьте добры работать с ним и вернуть в исходном как-бы состоянии.

Вот в таком варианте да

```
HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(...);
JDBCWrapper jdbcWrapper = new JDBCWrapper(dataSource);
// работа с wrapper
wrapper.close();
dataSource.close();
```

В таком варианте нет

```
JDBCWrapper jdbcWrapper = new JDBCWrapper(new HikariDataSource(...));
// работа с wrapper
wrapper.close();
```

PS. Мнение личное прошу не холиварить